# inline div background not showing up

Tags: css, background-image, repeat, background-position

I'm trying to use two divs, one with a non repeating background in the left corner to serve as a 'curved border' image, and the second div, within that one, with a background that is offset by the width of the first div's image so that it seems to be one solid image, that fluidly stretches with the page width.  I tried doing this the way I described but it isn't working, only the stretched repeating background div shows up.  I would prefer to try from scratch something one of you suggests.

Comment: Does the first div have an explicit width set on it?

Comment: We need some sample code, here. And know the browser you are testing it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting an explicit widh on the left div, and try using float:left on both (to make sure they align properly).

And set border:none (I'm stating the obvious here, probably).